How can I make the cursor state persist between pages?
I implemented a cursor from this library https://cursor.oooo.so/ in my portfolio made with astro and preact, my jsx file looks like this:
import { useEffect } from "preact/hooks";
import { initCursor, updateCursor } from "ipad-cursor";


const CustomCursor = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.cursorInitialized) {
      // Inicializa el cursor solo una vez
      initCursor({
        normalStyle: { background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" },
        textStyle: { background: "blue" },
        blockStyle: { background: "green" },
      });
      window.cursorInitialized = true;
    }

    // Asegura que el cursor se actualice al cambiar de página
    updateCursor();
  }, []);

  return nul; // Este componente no necesita renderizar nada
};

export default CustomCursor;


I implemented this in my layout like this:
<html>
  <body class="dark:bg-[#0e0e0e] bg-white">
    <!-- <article
            class="bg-[url('noise.gif')] fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen opacity-[0.025] z-[-1] pointer-events-none"
        >
        </article> -->
    <slot />
    <Cursor client:load transition:name="cursor" transition:persist/>
    <Button animate="hidden">
      <ThemeSwitcher />
    </Button>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>

it is assumed that adding transition:name y transition:persist, Adding this is supposed to persist the state but when I navigate to another page the cursor changes to the Windows cursor and I have to reload the page for it to work again

you're using view transitions? if so, you might need to call init again on astro:page-load event?

Yes, I use "viewtransitions", where should I place that?, If I delete the viewtrasition it works perfectly

probably just at the bottom of the Astro page. there you can also call initCursor. i don't think you need a react component at all, then you are not forced to use useEffect.
